# How to Format the DateTime of Scanned Files List?

Tags: c#

I scan a directory for png files and put their modified dates in a List.

But how can I format the `DateTime`?

I would like to keep `Date` and remove `Time`.

---

```
List<DateTime> MyFileDates = Directory.GetFiles("C:\\Images\\", "*.png")
.Select(File.GetLastWriteTime)
.ToList();
```

---

I tried using `.ToString("dd/MM/yy")` but it gives error
`No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments.`

```
List<DateTime> MyFilesDates = Directory.GetFiles("C:\\Images\\", "*.png")
.Select(File.GetLastWriteTime)
.ToString("dd/MM/yy")
.ToList();
```

Comment: You're using `File.GetLastWriteTime` in your `.Select` where you should be doing something along the lines of `.Select(x => File.GetLastWriteTime(x).ToString("dd/MM/yy")).ToList();` - what you're doing is saying the `IEnumerable()` result needs to be parsed to the date string.

Comment: @DeeKayy90 Would you be able to show an example of how to use `x =>`.

Comment: See Nino's answer, I think he just got in before me :) The difference being we both used one-character variables, he has chosen `p` and I used `x`.

Comment: @MattMcManis [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions)'s short guide about Lambda expressions..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's two ways of achieving this. One is to convert `List<DateTime>` to `List<string>` with strings formatted to `dd/MM/yy`

```
 List<string> MyFilesDates = Directory.GetFiles("C:\\Images\\", "*.png")
    .Select(p => File.GetLastWriteTime(p)
    .ToString("dd/MM/yy"))
    .ToList();
```

Other way is to remove time component (set it to 00:00:00):

```
List<DateTime> MyFilesDates = Directory.GetFiles("C:\\Images\\", "*.png")
    .Select(p => File.GetLastWriteTime(p))
    .Select(p => new DateTime(p.Year, p.Month, p.Day))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this.

Comment: The second method worked, it removed Time and I was able to keep List<DateTime>.

Comment: glad i could help :)

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks fine, except you gotta put the ToString on each DateTime, instead you put it on the list. So you go

```
List<string> MyFilesDates = Directory.GetFiles("C:\\Images\\", "*.png")
.Select(p => File.GetLastWriteTime(p)  // closing parenthesis moved from here...
.ToString("dd/MM/yy"))  // ...to here
.ToList();
```

instead and it should be fine.

Comment: It gave the error `Cannot implicity convert type List<string> to List<System.DateTime>`

Comment: Whoops, thanks Nino! Was wondering why it worked in my code but not in his :D
Working too much with `var` I guess.

Comment: @MattMcManis there was wrong type of List, i have edited Metalkiller's answer.

Comment: @Metallkiller copy/paste happens :)

Comment: @Nino Exactly that :)
Also I just realized, I wrote exactly the same thing as you. Sorrry about that.

Comment: @Metallkiller well, looks like your answer is a good suggestion :) Here's an upvote!

Comment: I am testing the two answers, because I think my program needs it to be List<DateTime> instead of <string>. I also use a DateTime.Parse() to compare dates.

Comment: @MattMcManis Since a `DateTime` object doesn't have a format, it seems the whole thing is pretty useless. If you need a `List<DateTime>`, you can really stop after the `.Select([...]);`, because that's when you have your `List<DateTime>`. The rest is only needed to get formatted strings representing each date.

Comment: Take a look at Nino's answer on the `<DateTime>` format. Your answer works, but to integrate it into my program I have to refactor some other code I have set to use `List<DateTime>`. I gave you an upvote, I may use your solution sometime in the future.